# CakePHP 2: How to generate an sql insert script from an array

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0, dump, sql-insert

Can I generate an sql insert statement from an array returned by find methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can.
After performing the find() operation iterate your data using foreach loop and make a string based insert query with ";" as separator after each insert query. Create a file with extension as .sql and use force download component to download it.
I have some sort of code that can help you. I'll try to give you the code soon.